# Why does this regex not match

Tags: java, type-conversion, equals

I'm building a regex pattern to validate my String inputted. 
Here is the limitations that i have to include;

```
The letters a to z (upper and lowercase) (zero or many times)
o The numbers 0 to 9 (between zero and three times)
o The ampersand (&) character (zero or may times)
o The space character (zero or one time)
```

Here is the regex I built and tested on

```
[a-zA-Z&]*|[0-9]{0,3}|[\s]?

String p1 = "[a-zA-Z\\&]*|[0-9]{0,3}|[\\s]?" ;
        if (bankName.matches(p1) && bankName.length() >= 8) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
```

Here is the entries I'm testing against.

```
tXiPkaodan57yzrCxYjVT
String bankName = "tXiPkaodan57yzrCxYjVT" ;
```

On the site i'm testing the regex on is not matching because the numbers ( 5 & 7 ) started and is between the letters but I have included in my regex pattern that it should beable to include any numbers range from 0-9, and 0-3 times 
https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output
The site i tested it on

Comment: Because you're defining a string that has 0 or more letters and ampersand OR 0 to 3 numbers OR space

Comment: Try wrapping the regular expression with `/` like: `"/[a-zA-Z\\&]*|[0-9]{0,3}|[\\s]?/"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bars ('or') in your regexes have the most precedence, so, that regexp reads:

Match if the input is precisely one of:

1. Either 0 or more characters that ALL match any letter (either case) or an ampersand,
2. anywhere between 0 and 3 digits
3. 0 or 1 space.

Your input is none of those things; it is a mix of those things. For example, the input 'a1a' does not match your regexp because, well, step through it: the 'a' forces the regexp matcher to pick the first of your 3 options above, and that's.. it. There's no going back now. Your regexp will match the a, fails to match on the 1, and that's the end of it.

So, how do you fix it? Not by sticking with regexp; that's not good solution for this problem. A regexp that precisely does what you asked for is very convoluted.

Instead, why not just loop through each character, and have 4 counters (spaces, digits, letters, and other stuff). For each character increment the right counter. Then at the end, check that the 'other stuff' counter is 0, digits is 3 or less, and spaces is 1 or less, and then it is valid. Otherwise, it is not.